# Page not found(404),Current path didn't match any of these

Tags: python, django

Views.py

```
From django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    Return HttpResponse('Hello World')
```

urls.py(my_app)

```
From Django.urls import path
From . Import views

Urlspatterns=[
    Path(' ',views.home)
]
```

Main urls

```
From django.urls import path, include
From Django.contrib import adim

Urlspatterns=[
    Path('admim/',.....)
    Path(' ',include('my_app.urls))
```

Settings.py

```
Installed apps=[
     " ",
     " ",
     'my_app',
]
```

Why I run the server it tells me page not found, ....... current empty path didn't match any of these, my Django has been working fine until recently, even if I start a new project from scratch it ends up with same result, I'm actually at the edge of giving up on Django ,I really need help please.... thanks in advance

Comment: `File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'From' is not defined`    Do you mean `from` ?

Comment: While running server or visiting url?

Comment: That was a typo error while asking the question,I'm using vscode so those little error normally gets corrected

Comment: Yes while running server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your empty url has `space` in `path` inside main `urls.py`.

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('my_app.urls'))
]
```

Also in your app `urls.py` remove `space` from url `path`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home)
]
```

Also you have typo error there is no `Urlspatterns` use `urlpatterns` instead and in case of `Installed apps` use `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Also in `views.py` `return` instead of `Return`

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello World')
```

And lastly in all files use `from` instead of `From`